# Terraform error in assigning diff types of maps in a conditional evaluation

Tags: terraform

In locals.tf, trying to assign pri map if id's are passed while in case of no id's being passed looking to pass pub map. The pri map has ids whereas pub map doesn't, how can I assign pri/pub to fvar?

```
locals {
  pub = {
    (var.zname) = {
      comment = var.zname
    }
  }
  pri = {
    (var.zname) = {
      comment = var.zname
      vpc     = [{ id = var.ids }]
    }
  }
  fvar = length(var.ids) != 0 ? local.pri : local.pub
}
```

Doing it above is throwing below error

```
│ Error: Inconsistent conditional result types
│ 
│   on .terraform/modules/hz/locals.tf line 14, in locals:
│   14:   fvar = length(var.ids) != 0 ? local.pri : local.pub
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.pri is object with 1 attribute "dev.db"
│     │ local.pub is object with 1 attribute "dev.db"
│     │ var.ids is list of string with 1 element
│ 
│ The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. Type
│ mismatch for object attribute "dev.db": The 'true' value
│ includes object attribute "vpc", which is absent in the 'false' value.
```

Is there any way to pass diff maps to the same variable (fvar)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like the message writes, `local.pub` and `local.pri` have **different types**. Specifically, your `local.pub` is missing `vpc` attribute, which you have in `local.pri`. Im a bool expression, you **can't mix** types.  So you have to make them to be of the same type, i.e. they must have **same attributes**.

You can add empty `vpc` list to your `local.pub` to fix that:

```
locals {
  pub = {
    (var.zname) = {
      comment = var.zname
      vpc = []
    }
  }
  pri = {
    (var.zname) = {
      comment = var.zname
      vpc     = [{ id = var.ids }]
    }
  }
  fvar = length(var.ids) != 0 ? local.pri : local.pub
}
```

Comment: when I do that the module which is being passed this variable is erroring out as its expecting some values in the vpc list. no alternative without vpc being passed in local.pub?

Comment: @nmakb You have to account for that empty vpc list. If you don't know how, please make new question specific to that issue.