# terraform how to deal with empty list

Tags: terraform

In the below piece of code, in local.pub empty vpc list is being passed so that the assignment to fvar succeeds as it needs both local.pub and local.pri to have same map elements. But in the target module where fvar is sent, if there is a map element for vpc - it expects an id which is empty in case of local.pub, how can I deal with this? How to make the assignment succeed and the same time handle passing of empty list to the submodule (PS: submodule cannot be changed to deal with empty vpc list)

```
locals {
  pub = {
    (var.zname) = {
      comment = var.zname
      vpc = []
    }
  }
  pri = {
    (var.zname) = {
      comment = var.zname
      vpc     = [{ id = var.ids }]
    }
  }
  fvar = length(var.ids) != 0 ? local.pri : local.pub
}
```

This is a follow-up question for this post - [Terraform error in assigning diff types of maps in a conditional evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76011353/terraform-error-in-assigning-diff-types-of-maps-in-a-conditional-evaluation/76011507#76011507)

Comment: Can you please provide example TF code where would you use `local.fvar` and where do you have a problem with the empty vpc `list`?

Comment: "submodule cannot be changed" Then there is likely nothing you can do as this is a code issue in the declared module.

Comment: @Marcin this is the module https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-route53/blob/master/modules/zones/main.tf